# No linebreaks after MySQL select

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've a MySQL database with some posts in (with linebreaks).

I select these by using this syntax:

```
public function getById($id) {
    $stmp = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT `content` FROM `posts` WHERE `id`= ?;");
    $stmp->execute(array($this->id));
    $row = $stmp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this->content = $row['content'];
}
```

But this way I lose the linebreaks. Is there a way that I can select the content included the linebreaks?

Sincerely,

LuxoJr

Comment: You are not losing the line breaks. Your browser is probably just ignoring them, as HTML wants to have a <br/> in stead of a line break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newlines in the database are saved as `\n` (newline) or `\r` (return) or a combination of those two. At the client side the webbrowser ignores those, thats why you dont see them, the only way to do that is converting them to `<br/>` (breaks)

Converts (`\n\r`, `\r\n`, `\n`, `\r`) to `<br/>`

```
nl2br($row['content']);
```

see php doc [nl2br function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score -2):

HTML transforms line feeds into spaces. Use this to turn them into visible line feeds in HTML:

```
$this->content = nl2br($row['content']);
```